# How to install request-promise in angular 9 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, request-promise

I created a angular 9 project with Angular CLI 9.1.5.

I install with npm in this project the request-promise library.

I start with :

`npm i request --save`
`npm i @type/request`
`npm i request-promise --save`
`npm i @type/request-promise`

When i run this project, i have a lot of error but i found online a solution, in my package.json i add :

> "browser": {
>       "crypto": false,
>       "http": false,
>       "https": false,
>       "net": false,
>       "path": false,
>       "stream": false,
>       "tls": false,
>       "os": false,
>       "zlib": false,
>       "fs": false
>     }

In my tsconfigconfig.app.json

I add :

> "types" : [***"node"***]

In my service i use :

```
import * as rp from 'request-promise';
export class test{
    rpget(){

        rp.get('xxxxxxxxxx').then(function(response2){
            // expect(response.statusCode).toBe('GET /200');
            /* console.log("respnse " + response2);

            }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            });
            }
}
```

When i run ng serve, compilation ending but in the browser console i have the following error :

undefined###undefined### The "request" library is not installed automatically anymore.undefined### But is a dependency of "request-promise".undefined### Please install it with:undefined### npm install request --saveundefined###undefined

But request is installed in this project.

Comment: Why not use the built in `HttpClient`?  It returns an `Observable` but rxjs has a `toPromise` operator to convert the obserable to a promise.  https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise

Comment: Because my code is finished with request-promise. I want to do webscraping. With HttpClient can I webscrape a website?

Comment: Can you help me pliz?